# Sharepoint Online Files with Microsoft Office 365 API Tools for Visual Studio 2013

Tags: api, sharepoint, office365, sharepoint-online

I'm using Office-365-APIs-Starter-Project-for-ASPNETMVC from https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-365-APIs-Starter-Project-for-ASPNETMVC for my first tests with this API Tools.
I can read the elements like files(OneDrive for Business), contacts and need the access to sharepoint online files. This example uses DiscoverCapabilityAsync("MyFiles") to get the ServiceEndpintUri. How can I get die Uri of SPO and my site? Where can I set the requestet Site and document library?
Best regards
Christoph

Answer (score 0):

@chmav, you'll need to first add the Sites capability. In the 
**Register app and configure the sample to consume Office 365 APIs** section of the readme.md, step 6, you'll want to add the Sites capability. To get the endpoint with this example, you'll probably use `DiscoverCapabilityAsync("Sites")` (I say probably since I haven't done this). You'll need to add a controller and view to handle the Sites data in this example.